# Does $.ajaxSetup control $.getJSON

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to turn off all AJAX in my application, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835090/how-to-turn-off-all-ajax-in-a-jquery-mobile-application).

Does using `ajaxSetup` control `getJSON`?

i.e. would this `getJSON` request be synchronous?

```
// TURNING OFF ALL AJAX
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});

$.getJSON(window.url_root + '/app/settings/1/', function(data) {
                window.authenticated = data['is_user_authenticated'];
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**! From `jQuery` site about [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

> All subsequent Ajax calls using any function will use the new
>   settings, unless overridden by the individual calls, until the next
>   invocation of $.ajaxSetup().
>
> Note: The settings specified here will affect all calls to $.ajax or
>   AJAX-based derivatives such as $.get(). This can cause undesirable
>   behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting
>   the normal default settings. For that reason we strongly recommend
>   against using this API. Instead, set the options explicitly in the
>   call or define a simple plugin to do so.

This is like a global settings for all `ajax` requests.